# Implementing UML Sequence Diagram

Tags: c++, uml, sequence-diagram

My question is relatively simple: how would I go about implementing a UML sequence diagram in C++ code? I was reading up on sequence diagrams the other day, and I found [this example](http://agilemodeling.com/images/models/sequenceDiagramBasicCourse.jpg) for a program for a student enrolling in a seminar.

How would I go about turning this diagram into a program? For the sake of this question, lets focus on one class, say the `EnrollInSeminar` controller. How would I go about implementing this?

I imagine that it might be something like this:

```
class EnrollInSeminar
{
public:
  void Activate();
};

void EnrollInSeminar::Activate()
{
  SecurityLogon logonUI{};
  Student theStudent = logonUI.getStudent();
  SeminarSelector seminarSelectorUI{};
  Seminar seminar = seminarSelectorUI.getSeminar();
  if (!seminar.isEligible(theStudent))
    return;
  theStudent.getSchedule().determineFit(seminar);
  Fee fee = StudentFees.calculateFees(seminar, theStudent);
  FeeDisplay feeUI{fee};
  if (!feeUI.getVerification())
    return;
  seminar.enrollStudent(theStudent);
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement the `EnrollInSeminar` class? If not, how should I do it?

Comment: I would recommend you convert your picture to PNG and include it directly in your question.

Comment: As for your question, I'm not so sure if your code meets all the lifetime requirements as shown in the diagram. All the instances you create are destroyed at the end of the functions scope. You probably need to put more scope blocks `{}` to meet the required points of destructor calls.

Comment: This diagram is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a SD does not tell anything about the methods being used in the messages passed from one object to another except the name, the parameters and - as the name says - the sequence. So the only thing you can draw from "just the SD" are methods and their parameters.

You will need additional information from a use case to know what the methods are all about. Without you simply can not "implement a SD".